# Errors installing Karma on Mac OS 10.8.5

Tags: karma-runner, gyp

When I run `npm install karma --save-dev`, most of the installation goes well, but I get the following errors:

```
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.6.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Volumes/myProject/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 

> bufferutil@1.1.0 install /Volumes/myProject/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
Error: Can't run /Applications/Xcode.app/usr/bin/xcodebuild (no such file).

Error: Can't run /Applications/Xcode.app/usr/bin/xcodebuild (no such file).

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
```

I have XCode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008) installed at /Applications/Xcode.app/, but when I Show Contents on the file, it shows a folder named Contents, and no `usr` directory.

What suggestions can you give to get gyp to install?